Ignite Configuration - How to do it Right way
Apache Ignite has different modes of deployment [ Server embedded, Thick Client, THin Client]
If we have to make Ignite Cache as Write Behind + Thick Client.

Where to configure the data source [ At Server node or Client node]   for Cache
Where to configure Cache configuration

Application is Spring boot, but we are not using the ignite auto configure.jar
& cache is initialized based on xml not application.yml. In Such cases Kindly clarify where to configure cache definitions, datasource Definition [ Server or client side]

There's not really a "right" answer. Defining your tables on either the servers or your (thick) clients is perfectly valid.
Whether you define your table on the client or server doesn't change where the data is stored or how it is fetched (or written back) to your source database. Those operations are always performed by the servers.
